# Arduino Uno R3 assembly code to push a button and turn on a LED

Tags: avr, assembly, platformio

I've been trying this for days without success...

I need to turn on a LED on portb when a button in portd is pushed. Cabling works, I've tested it with Arduino IDE and it works like a charm.

This is what I got so far:

```
.global main
.equ LED, PB5
.equ BUTTON, PD3
main:
   ldi r22,0xff                    ;all bits in portb are output
   out _SFR_IO_ADDR(DDRB),r22      
   ldi r21,0x00                    ;all bits in portd are input
   out _SFR_IO_ADDR(DDRD),r21
   ldi r19, 0b00000000             ;unpushed button
   ldi r18, 0b00100000             ;pushed button
   eor r16, r16
loop:
   out BUTTON, r16                 ;read button to r16
   cp r16, r18                     ;compare r16 with r19 (button on)
   cbi _SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTB),LED
   breq loop                       ;go back to loop
   sbi _SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTB),LED     ;if z=1, turn led on turn led on
   rjmp loop                       ;back to loop
```

It is much easier with `sbis`, if I got it right...

```
#include <avr/io.h>
.equ LED, PB5
.global main
ldi r16,0xff
out _SFR_IO_ADDR(DDRB),r16
ldi r16,0x00
out _SFR_IO_ADDR(DDRD),r16

main:
    sbis portd, 3
    rjmp ledoff
    ldi r16,0xff
    sbi _SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTB),LED   ; turn on led
    rjmp main
ledoff:
    ldi r16,0x00
    cbi _SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTB),LED   ; turn off led
    rjmp main
```

But I got this error compiling:

```
.pio\build\uno\src\main.o: In function `main':
(.text+0x8): undefined reference to `portd'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** [.pio\build\uno\firmware.elf] Error 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

> ```lisp
>    ldi r18, 0b00100000             ;pushed button
> ```

does not match the definition of `BUTTON`. You are setting bit 5 of
the register, whereas the button is on bit 3. In order to avoid
this kind of error, I would rather write

```lisp
   ldi r18, _BV(BUTTON)            ;pushed button
```

Then, here:

> ```lisp
>    out BUTTON, r16                 ;read button to r16
> ```

you are not reading anything: you are writing somewhere. I guess you
mean:

```lisp
   in r16, _SFR_IO_ADDR(PIND)      ;read button to r16
```

Note that this reads the whole port at once. If you are only interested
in one bit, you should then

```lisp
   andi r16, _BV(BUTTON)           ;keep only the relevant bit
```

before the comparison.

One last thing: you may want to read about the `sbis` and `sbic`
instructions: they could simplify the code you have here.

---

**Edit**: answering the updated question.

> undefined reference to `portd'

This is because there is no such thing as “portd”. You mean
`_SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTD)`. Well, no, you should actually use
`_SFR_IO_ADDR(PIND)`, as this is the port *input* register, whereas
`PORTD` is the *output* register.

A couple of extra notes:

- Do not put code before `main`: it will not be executed, as the C
  runtime jumps to `main` after its initialization.
- The instructions `ldi r16, …` within the main loop serve no purpose:
  you are not using this register after the program initialization.